# Why is this private route permission check not working in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used to have a simple private route component where I checked for the state of authentication and based on the "true or false" result it redirected the user to the login page if false, or to the main page otherwise.

It looked like this

```js
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

export default ({
  component: Component,
  render: renderFn,
  authed,
  name,
  ...rest
}) => {
  //The privateroute is fed with the auth state of app.js and evaluates the render based on that . If flase always renders "/"
  if (Component) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authed === true ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      //Second case is for iframe based renders
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authed === true ? (
            renderFn(props)
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
};
```

Now the point is, that I decided to implement a permission system. My permission list is coming from a cookie which contains a jwt, so I use the following code.

```js
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
var jwtDecode = require("jwt-decode");
export default ({
  component: Component,
  render: renderFn,
  authed,
  name,
  ...rest
}) => {
  var accesstoken = Cookies.get("accesstoken");
  var decoded = jwtDecode(accesstoken); //["landingpage","registerpage"]
  console.log("accesstoken  inside the private route: ");
  console.log(decoded.permited); //["landingpage","registerpage"] --> those are the only routes permited for the current user
  console.log(name); //name of the component being accessed --> "heimdall"
  console.log(
    "is the name of the component being accessed included in the decoded jwt?"
  );
  console.log(decoded.permited.includes(name)); //false -> should return the "false" action, redirect to login

  //The privateroute is fed with the auth state of app.js and evaluates the render based on that . If flase always renders "/"
  if (Component) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authed === true && this.decoded.permited.includes(name) === true ? ( //the second check after && is not working , it should equal to "true && false == false" , but it returns true
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      //Second case is for iframe based renders
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authed === true ? (
            renderFn(props)
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work as per commented in my code. The lines above the main `if` all return what expected. But then during the check apparently a "true && (what is supposed to be) false" is returning true, so the check is never failing as it should.

Whats going on?

**EDIT:** Ihave figured out that the code is and was always returning else, and i wasnt aware of that. Im debugging it right now

Comment: Why using  ```this.decoded.permited.includes(name)``` , just use ```decoded.permited.includes(name)```

Comment: @SargisIsoyan true i forgot to remove that trying to find the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in my code. I had to move the logic of the if condition to the else one.